# Finding a matrix representation for two Grassmann numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quantum-field-theory, grassmannian

This question is more general in the sense that I want to know how one finds a particular (say matrix) representation for any object. For the case of Grassmann numbers we have from [Wikipedia the following representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number#Matrix_representations):

> Grassmann numbers can always be represented by matrices. Consider, for example, the Grassmann algebra
>   generated by two Grassmann numbers $\theta_1$ and
>   $\theta_2$. These Grassmann numbers can be represented by
>   4×4 matrices:
>
> $$\theta_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 &
>  0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}\qquad \theta_2 =
>  \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&-1&0&0\\
>  \end{bmatrix}\qquad \theta_1\theta_2 = -\theta_2\theta_1 =
>  \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}.
>  $$

How do one find these matrices? Do you guess them or is there a procedure? What about finding differenct matrix-representations for **Dirac $\gamma$-matrices? How do you find them?**

Answer (score 1):

you seem to have double posted your question. I provided an answer at:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95259/how-do-you-find-a-particular-representation-for-grassmann-numbers/95664#95664